# How to get current hex code color from an UIView programmatically

Tags: ios

I would like to know is it possible to get current hex code color from an UIView programmatically.

I know we can get it easily on Storyboard. But how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
 CGFloat red = self.view.backgroundColor.CIColor.red;
 CGFloat blue = self.view.backgroundColor.CIColor.blue;
 CGFloat green = self.view.backgroundColor.CIColor.green;
 CGFloat alpha = self.view.backgroundColor.CIColor.alpha;
```

In return you got RGB.

Comment: This doesn't give a hex code for the color.